# What are the benefits of developing chatboat using MxNet rather than API.AI (DialogFlow), LUIS, WIT.AI or any other AI framework?

Tags: azure-language-understanding, wit.ai, mxnet, dialogflow-es

I want to develop own chatbot for my retail store project. I have checked different frameworks like API.AI (DialogFlow), LUIS, WIT.AI and Whatsan virtual agent. But I also come across [MXNet](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/). So if I develop my own chatbot using MxNet then what will be advantageous over other above discussed inbuilt API

Comment: may I know why negative rank?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Advantage of MXNet over existing framework

MXNet deep learning framework can be used to implement, train and deploy deep neural networks that can solve text categorization and sentiment analysis problems.

** Improves Synonyms, Hypernyms, and Hyponyms**

Let’s suppose that the users asks for a soda, but your chatbot only knows specific terms such as coca-cola or pepsi, that are hyponyms of soda. Hypernyms, synonyms, and hyponyms can be handled in English because there are a lot of NLP resources, called thesaurus and ontologies, but they are usually for general language. Therefore, coca-cola, a very specific domain term, is unlikely to be part of this kind of resources.

You could try to find an existing thesaurus that fits your problem or build it by your own. Resources built by domain experts are expensive but highly accurate. With Machine Learning you can create linguistic(Langauge base) resources, particularly with Deep Learning techniques, that could be good enough to your use case.

**Final Conclusion**

- If We build Chat from scratch using MXNet, we need machine learning
  experience, we need resources and time. It’s open source we can’t get
  immediate support as well.  So, other alternative is use a
  combination of a tool for solving general NLP problems (i.e.
  Dialogflow, Wit.ai, IBM watson agent assist etc.) plus custom server
  side logic for more powerful features.

[Source](https://dzone.com/articles/building-a-chatbot-analysis-amp-limitations-of-mod)

Answer (score 1):

MXNet is a deep learning framework which can do general model training and inference.  What API.AI, Amazon Lex, WIT.AI, etc. do is provide a platform that *uses* this training and inference, but is itself a separate engine and not a deep learning framework.
API.AI, for instance, offers dialog and context constructs, which allow a conversation to take place while filling in data slots as the conversation proceeds, but this is out of the scope of a deep learning engine.  The chatbot platform will utilize deep learning engines (and their models) for its subtasks such as speech recognition and conversion of spoken/written text to canonical form.